# system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType not showing battery level?

Tags: bash, battery, headphones, airpods

Up until a week ago, I was able to see the battery level on my both my Sony Headphones and my AirPods, using the command `system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType`. But now, all of a sudden, it doesn't show my battery level on my Sony Headphones (even though I'm still able to see it in the bluetooth menubar), but it still shows the battery level on my AirPods.

Any idea on why it suddenly stopped showing the battery level? Or how to get it to show again?

[image: Screenshot of the output of the command system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType]

Comment: This is *read only data*.  If the device doesn't report through this mechanism, you aren't going to force it.  Fortunately, the linked dupe provides you a way to obtain battery level of connected devices.

Comment: @Allan I have looked at the link previously, but didn't seem to get it to work. I'm not having any luck using the ioreg command to get neither the battery level of the AirPods nor other headphones

Comment: I just seems weird that I was able to get this information a week ago, but can't get the same information now.

Comment: Did you update macOS and/or your headphone's software/firmware?  `system_profiler` reads data of the devices attached to your computer.  If it sends it (like your AirPods) then it will report it.  If not (like your Sony now) it won't get it.  If it's showing up in the menu bar, it means *something* is sending that data and normally `ioreg` can access it.